# Pass a value from ASP.Net to an ASP classic page?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a login page in ASP.Net, but I need to pass the user details to the welcome page which is a classic ASP page. How can I do this? (Except query string)

Comment: Kindly help us by providing the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt the user-details and pass through `query-string`.

**or**

Write in to a `Cookie` and access it from asp page.

Sessions can not be shared among ASP.NET and Classic-asp, you need to set session variables again in your classic-asp page for using in the rest of asp pages.

Comment: Not entirely true. Sessions can be shared by changing the approach so session state is maintained in a centralised location such as a database. But this approach can be a lot of work for not a lot of gain in the long run.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, very true.